# Apache/bin/httpd: symbol lookup error: Apache/bin/httpd: undefined symbol: apr_brigade_split_ex

Tags: apache

I am getting the below error when trying to perform `phpinfo.php`.

> Apache/bin/httpd: symbol lookup error: Apache/bin/httpd: undefined symbol: apr_brigade_split_ex

I am running Apache 2.4.7. Strangely when I run `httpd -V` I notice that Apache is compiled with higher version of `apr-util` however server loads only 1.2.7 version which is lower than 1.5.3.

```
[itapps@sgerp12uatap4 logs]$ httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Unix)
Server built:   Jan 22 2014 12:11:39
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:27
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.0, APR-UTIL 1.2.7
Compiled using: APR 1.5.0, APR-UTIL 1.5.3
```

Can anybody help in how to make the server load 1.5.3 version of `apr-util`?
Also please help me to resolve `undefined symbol: apr_brigade_split_ex`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure a 1.5.x apr-util is in your shared library search path, earlier than that 1.2.x, when apache is started.

Typically httpd is invoked by apachectl, and apachectl sources a specific envvars file.  That would be a good place to setup your shared library path to prefer the newer apr-util.

If this is Linux, the var you want to prepend to is LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: Hi covener,
The LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my env is 
[itapps@sgerp12uatap4 logs]$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/export/home/itapps/LSurvey/APR/lib::/export/home/itapps/LSurvey/APR-UTIL/lib:/export/home/itapps/LSurvey/pcre/lib:/export/home/itapps/LSurvey/Apache/lib

Comment: how to make the server load 1.5.3 version of apr-util ? can you please give assist me by giving example